# What to do with first gen Apple TV with screen artifacting

Tags: appletv, visual-artifacts

So i bought a used Apple TV from some unscrupulous jerk on Craigslist and realized upon plugging it in that it has some pixellation/screen artifacting issues - possibly due to heat issues or a fried GPU. This happens instantly though, so I'm not positive modifying its thermal dissipation characteristics will help.

I did notice that after I cracked it open and directed a box fan directly into the unit along with setting it to 1080p, the artifacting has been greatly reduced (but still enough to be annoying)

Does anyone have any ideas of what to do next?  Some ideas that have crossed my mind

1. open it up and redo the thermal paste ala 360 RROD fix and hope it fixes the issue?
2. upgrade the fan somehow or move it to new chassis with better cooling? (seems like an awful lot of trouble for this thing)
3. put XBMC/boxee on this and hope it doesn't stress the machine in the same way and miraculously makes the artifacting go away?
4. throw it out the window and wait for them to get boxee/xbmc working on the new ATV?

If anyone has some advice or can direct me to some guidance, it'd be greatly appreciated!